# know the methods and classes running in a complicated java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently using a complicated open source java project with 10 packages and each packages having at least 7 classes each (eclipse is the IDE i'm using). It is a project with multiple usages/application. I'm only using 1 usage of the project so i dont need most of the other classes. I was able to run it and is giving me the output it says it would. I'm trying to edit the code or to insert a java computation so that i can have better output. But since the java project is too complicated for me, i don't know the specific classes/methods that are being used when the project is being ran for the usage that i want. When a project is running how do i know the flow of the classes/methods so that i will know the flow of the variables and so that i will know where to insert a different computation or algorithm. thanks

Comment: @ what is that  open source project?

Comment: freesim - traffic simulator - http://www.freewaysimulator.com/download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only 10 tiny packages? That's a VERY simple project you are working with. But anyway, try this: make your procedure (the code that calls the project's methods) repeat in an endless loop and have `jvisualvm` started and connected to your JVM. That's a Java profiler distributed with the JDK. It will give you the rundown on all code paths being taken. Only, it will expose you to the full complexities of a live JVM (many threads). You'll have to find yourself around.

Comment: thanks Marko, yes 10 packages is already alot for me which reveals that i'm a java newbie... i honestly have no idea yet of what you shared but i'll try to figure them out

Comment: Just try and start jvisualvm from the command line. It's a GUI tool, you might figure things out. But if you only have a JRE installed, not the full JDK, then this will not work.

Comment: Im reading things about it right now... will it not be a headache for a newbie like me...is it easy to check the flow of classes and methods  when a project is running?

Comment: It depends very much on the complexity of your code. You can use the debugger, as david99world suggested, or you can navigate the code statically, using ctrl-click and such.

Comment: Thread dump only gives you a snapshot. Do you see the Sampler tab? There click on the CPU button. This will start sampling the activity in your app. After a while press Stop and then Snapshot -- then you'll get the rundown of all activity in all threads. Now just find the main thread that executed your code and you should see the complete call tree of everything that was executed.

Comment: did see sampler tab and cpu button...what do you mean by complete call tree ? how can i find that?

Comment: Well, did you go through all the steps? Run the app with an endless loop, then click CPU on the Sampler tab, let it run for a while, then Stop, then Snapshot? A table opens with all the threads listed and each entry expands to the call tree of that thread (all code paths taken).

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger and step through the code to watch changes in the variables.

You could also throw in a few System.out lines if you want a bit more of a dirty method.

Might be worth having a quick skim over

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: thanks ...this is the first once i tried...i did see what is running when i ran the a part of the project but the middle part of the ui of the project will not completely run... cant see what will happen when the project connects to a socket and that's where i want to see the classes and codes that are running

Comment: when i made breakoints and tried to run the project using debugger, i cannot continue when i open the login page of the ui so i cannot see the rest of the classes and methods

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint say, when the socket connects and either step in or step over the code from there.  As a bit of a shot in the dark, are you using a hot deploy or something like that where it might not be taking into consideration any code you recently changed?  If you're using something like JBoss, it might be worth restarting it before trying the debugger again.

Comment: hi david99world when the project is running, it is printing out strings in the console . ithought of writing additional system.out.println(....display some variables) beside them to displace some variables but they will not be printed put in the console what can the be the reason?

Comment: are any exceptions being thrown before hand stopping the code being ran?

Comment: the project will run as if i didn't add additional system.out.println... no errors or additional exceptions in the console or printout...it just ran as if i didn't add anything(this is when i didnt run it using debug ) i just throw system.out lines

Comment: david99world  im a java newbie and i dont quite get your question - "are you using a hot deploy or something like that where it might not be taking into consideration any code you recently changed?" what i know is im using eclipse ide with java classes, jars, where the project connects via socket to a client, connects to mysql, displays the output in a ui with google maps

Comment: when i try to run the simulator using eclipse debugger the login tab of the gui is grayed out so i cannot continue but if i run it normaly using eclipse i can login